# crash while replacing string

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I've written this code to replace string in substring (even if previous string was smaller than new). My problem is: crash while `RtlMoveMemory()`

Here is my function:

```
char* strreplace(char* s, const char* s1, const char* s2)
{
    char* p = strstr(s, s1);
    if (p != NULL) {
        size_t len1 = lstrlenA(s1);
        size_t len2 = lstrlenA(s2);
        if (len1 != len2) 
        {
            RtlMoveMemory(p + len2, p + len1, lstrlenA(p + len1) + 1);
        }

        RtlCopyMemory(p, s2, len2);
    }
    return s;
}
```

Comment: Could show a complete and reproducible sample code?

Comment: If this issue solved you can accept helpful answer or post your own.

Answer (score 0):

`RtlMoveMemory` does not allocate any memory, so your program will crash if the new string is longer than the old string.

Is there any good reason that you are trying to do this with `RtlMoveMmeory` and `RtlCopyMemory` instead of standard functions?